# Invalid type "string | null" of template literal expression. while sending authorization

Tags: typescript, axios, vuejs3

Ts-eslint stopped me with the message `"Invalid type "string | null" of template literal expression"` when I was trying to execute authorization.

The value came from localstorage so it has to be `null` or `string` but also I have to combine it with `Bearer`.

```js
   onMounted(async ()=>{
      let myToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
      
      await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/getdocuments', 
        {headers:{'Authorisation':`Baerer ${myToken}`}}
      )
      .then((res)=>{
          console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err=>{
          console.log(err);
      })
    })
```

Comment: how about {'Authorisation':``Baerer ${myToken || ''}``}

Comment: myToken can be with null value in you case

Answer (score 4):

I think this request should be called only if token is present

```
onMounted(async ()=>{
      let myToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
      if (!myToken) {
        console.warn('token is empty');
      } else {
        await axios.post(
          'http://localhost:3000/getdocuments', 
          {headers:{'Authorisation':`Baerer ${myToken}`}}
        )
        .then((res)=>{
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is late, but ran into the same error and just fixed it using a null guard check.

After you grab your token,

```
if (!myToken) {
    // Error handle
}
```